# Whats going wrong with the Hinge

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

[image]

With the boolean modifier, I try to cut both the end, what's going wrong, and why there is overlapping. I want to make a hinge so that it can fold, Any suggestions or help? thanks

[image]

Comment: First question: Do you have the scale applied to both objects? (In Object mode, Ctrl-A > Scale.) If you do then you'll need to share your file so that we can see what's going on. https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions there.

Comment: @JohnEason Yes scale are applied, and i have attach the file, plz check the question.

Comment: Looks as if the Y dimensons and spacing of your cutter object is wrong at a quick glance.

Comment: @JohnEason did not get what u mean

Comment: there is this "overlapping" because your individual meshes in the Cutter1 object are not wide enough. They have to be wider than the meshes in Cutter2

Comment: it gets pretty obvious, if you just move your one part to the side: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTbAI.jpg

Comment: @Chris how to solve any suggestion plz

Comment: @atek increase the cutter size

Comment: as Harry and Markus already commented...just change the cutter sizes

Comment: @Chris i tried but the below part also getting overlap

Comment: so pls upload the new blend file with your new try